# Can't load file from URL, but works with local path

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to load an XML file, but for some reason I can't use a URL.

`allow_url_fopen` is set to `On`.

I used this, which didn't work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://example.corn/test.xml");
```

But this does work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../test.xml");
```

I also tried `file_get_contents`:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("https://example.corn/test.xml");
```

and even `cURL`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.corn/test.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);          
curl_close($ch);
```

For each example I am displaying the output with `var_dump($xml);`, which always shows `bool(false)` when using a URL and shows the correct XML data when using a local path.

I would just use the local path, but this is just for a test and the actual XML file I am going to fetch is from a different site.

I tested it on a local server and it worked, but on my hosted server, it doesn't work at all. They are using the same `php.ini`. My hosted server is using php-fpm, I'm unsure if that could be a factor, or if there is something that has to be changed with it.

This might be a configuration error that I am unaware of, because the code should work, and the link definitley exists, because I can click on it and see the correct xml in the browser.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: If your code lies on the same server as the domain .. You may need to add the domain to the hosts file.  IE `127.0.0.1       example.com`  (assuming your web server is set to `127.0.0.1` which most are.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Does the file exist?

Comment: @Zak I tried with a different URL from a different server and It still didn't work.

Comment: @kerbh0lz I'm not getting an error, the file does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had my `openssl.cafile` property set to some location that didn't exist.

For some reason no errors were showing when using the commands above.

Answer (score -1):

I think the specified url is not valid or doesn't exist

- Read about curl in the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

  ```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
  ```

Comment: It definitley exists because I can go to the link in the browser. I'm starting to think it is something to do with my confirguration and not a code error.